# I received a crash. I have a very interesting exceptions. What is it?

Tags: ios, exception, crash

I received a crash. I have a very interesting exceptions. What is it?

```
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x11c06ac0 (object 0x11c06a30, a NSException)
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x113b9de sp=0xbfffe6d0] for exception 0x11c06aa0
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x113b9de sp=0xbfffe6d0] for exception 0x11c06aa0
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x11c06aa0 at 0x113bb9c
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: finishing handler
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: throwing 0x11ea1220 (object 0x11c06a30, a NSException)
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x113bb8c sp=0xbfffe6d0] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x24b7d83 sp=0xbffff410] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x113bb8c sp=0xbfffe6d0] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x24b7d83 sp=0xbffff410] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x11ea1200 at 0x24b7e16
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: rethrowing current exception
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x24b7ddf sp=0xbffff410] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: terminating
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: searching through frame [ip=0x2731eed sp=0xbffff3a0] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: catch(id)
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: unwinding through frame [ip=0x2731eed sp=0xbffff3a0] for exception 0x11ea1200
objc[4841]: EXCEPTIONS: handling exception 0x11ea1200 at 0x2731eff
2012-05-03 15:17:22.803 A[4841:16d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x2581022 0x2731cd6 0x256e33e 0x256f1f0 0x11e149 0x2582e99 0x89a89 0x2582e42 0x113b9df 0x255594f 0x24b8b43 0x24b8424 0x24b7d84 0x24b7c9b 0x27137d8 0x271388a 0x1473626 0x2e6d 0x2de5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'` means that you are trying to use NSMutableArray's -insertObject:atIndex: with an index value that is higher than the actual count of the array (and as it turns out, it's empty).

Comment: Ok, but what does exceptions mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were trying to insert data into an array in an index positon that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The line starting with the date seems to have the best chance of finding out what is going on.

There is not really enough info in this question though.